# Check String equality where order is not important

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I have the following code:

```
#Write the lines back which do NOT match the command
for line in lines:
    if line != command:
        file_writer.write(line)
```

And two example **Strings** I have are:

```
lines = [
    """user_operations.add_user("url",531,{u'Username': u'TEST123567', u'Status': u'Enabled', u'AccessTypes': [u'APN'], u'Auth': u'ServicePassword', u'ID': 7400, u'PasswordInfo': None, u'SSOInfo': None, u'Email': u'', u'AccountID': 531},False,headers)""",
    """user_operations.add_user("url",531,{u'Username': u'TEST123567', u'Status': u'Enabled', u'Email': u'', u'PasswordInfo': None, u'AccessTypes': [u'APN'], u'AccountID': 531, u'ID': 7400, u'Auth': u'ServicePassword', u'SSOInfo': None},False,headers)"""
]
```

Is there any quick 'n' dirty function to check if they contain the same data regardless of the order?

Thanks!

Comment: The example lines seem to be python commands. Are you getting the data in `lines` as strings or python commands ?

Comment: You question needs clarification. For example -- and I don't know if this is even the best question to ask -- do the input lines always start with `user_operations.add_user`, in which case the real issue is whether the data inside the parentheses is the same? Or do the input lines take many different forms?

Comment: The two lines are Strings (they are in fact python commands but that is irrelevant.) , I need some code which performs the same as the code I posted but will match strings where the order of the sub-strings does not matter.

Comment: If you can get the data out, you could use `ast.literal_eval` to make an actual python dict out of the data, then compare those.

Comment: Any comment down-voter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting a list of strings in `lines`, the following code should work:

```
#Write the lines back which do NOT match the command
sorted_command = sorted(command)
for line in lines:
    if sorted(line) != sorted_command:
        file_writer.write(line)
```

Comment: how you will get a list of strings, can you show me that ? this won't work if work please show me the full snippet.

Comment: you ve unquoted string, like headers which won't work in python. how you will take care of that.

Comment: The input should be correctly quoted strings. I think the question was unclear on that end.

Comment: it could be unquoted if comes out from java script.